# Relation between Ionization energy and reactivity

Tags: reactivity, periodic-trends, periodic-table

So I was learning about the periodic table where I came across the topic of ionization energy. As a general trend the Ionization energy decreases as we move down a group with a few exceptions such as copper having a greater value of Ionization energy than silver and a few more examples. But on going through the reactivity series Copper is placed above Silver this can also imply that a lot of energy is required to remove an electron from copper than silver so it be said that copper should be less reactive than silver but the opposite is true. Is there any other reason affecting reactivity?

Comment: All the chain of elementary - real or formal - processes has to be considered, both thermodynamically and kinetically. E.g.  Cu(s) -> Cu(g) -> Cu^2+(g) -> Cu^2+(aq), versus Ag(s) -> Ag(g) -> Ag+(g) -> Ag+(aq)

Comment: If you’re just getting started on the properties of elements, I’d say stick to whatever is being taught for now. Because chemistry is a pretty vast subject that seldom has rules that are followed throughout. There’s always exceptions and many different things that come into play. When you have a pretty good view of all other topics, you can ask yourself such questions, and have a much better chance of finding the solution. +1 for the curiosity though!

Comment: There's isn't really much of a relation between the two, whatever you mean by "reactivity" which isn't some parameter like ionization energy, that could be compared.